# What's the best way to make copies of a PMCD in a regular desktop?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, burning

I need to make ~500 copies of a PMCD using two regular desktop computers. One of them is running Windows 7 and the other Ubuntu 10.04. What I want is a reliable tool that let me burn the cd and also verify it. The copies are going to be audio cds so I'm trying to avoid any burning error or at least identify a bad copy so I can throw it away.

Should I use the regular burning software (like nero on windows and brasero on ubuntu), or is there  more reliable application that can do this job?

Comment: what is a PMCD?

Comment: PMCD (PreMaster CD) is a specially formatted, recordable Compact Disc designed to be sent to a CD pressing plant for replication [..]
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PMCD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many CD burners can also do verification after the burn.
One free example of such a product is [CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/).

However, even if you verify them on your system, there's no guarantee that they'll play properly on someone else's. I'd recommend using good media and using a cleaning CD before starting and every so often, then testing the result on several other computers before making the 500 run. In case of problems, your CD drive might need to be recalibrated by a professional (or replaced).

To burn a whole stack of CDs in one go, rather than one at a time, you will need specialized copier devices. You might search for companies supplying such services in your area.